# Firefox - image showing plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there any plugin/addon which shows all images which are used in the page ? (both CSS/HTML)

Web Developer tool does my half job. 
Is there any plugin which helps to list all images with height and width ?

Comment: Images which are used in the page

Answer (score 0):

There is the web developper toolbar plugin that has a section reserved for images operations. It also includes a lot of useful tools for web development in general.

Here is a link to download the plugin :
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Comment: Web Developer tool does my half job. Is there any plugin which helps to list all images with height and width ?

Comment: Web Developer lists all images but i want to extract the image path to a external file.